# Beginner using Arch Linux, “One or more pgp signatures could not be verified.” How to solve?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    spotify-1.2.26.1187-1-Release ... %s is unable to verify the signature.
gpg
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
```

I cant find this mystical "local gpg key pair" they are talking about.

I set up some sort of GPG key (I think) after trying to follow a tutorial but no luck.

Any help?

Comment: We are not a forum.   Why are you worried about Spotify? Do you need that application?  Is that the only signature that cannot be verified? I was able to find the solution without much fanfare.  [`curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_6224F9941A8AA6D1.gpg  | gpg --import -a`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotify#comment-904491)

Comment: ... Or you can install the SNAP version: https://snapcraft.io/spotify

Comment: @ChanganAuto: That would require installing Snap first, which only replaces OP's problem with two other problems. Not all Linux questions are about Ubuntu.

Comment: @u1686_grawity SNAP is agnostic and what two other problems are you talking about?  It can be easily installed in Arch (already in AUR) and it's a one-time action. That's from Canonical is immaterial here.

Answer (score 0):

So doing just a little bit of digging I was able to find the following answer on a [different thread](https://superuser.com/a/1210759/1843540), which recommends simply importing the necessary PGP keys for the given software using the gpg command ([man-page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/gpg.1.en), [arch-wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG))

Since you didn't provide the command you entered to get the error output, I'm not sure which spotify client you were attempting to download (`spotify-launcher/extra`, `spotify (AUR)`, etc).

Assuming you were going for the AUR package, gromit posted a [comment](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/spotify#comment-953231) on the package page about how to import the GPG key. I'm not too familiar with actually importing these keys, so I couldn't tell you if gromit's command will do all the work for you, or if you still need to manually install it afterwards using the method on the superuser thread, but I'd guess the command likely works all on its own. Keep in mind what he added at the end about the keys changing often.

If you're trying to download a client other than the AUR version, you'll have to find some other way of obtaining the relevant pgp key, then importing it using the first method listed.